# Cross-validation for paragraph-vector model

Tags: scikit-learn, transform, cross-validation, gensim

I just came across an error when trying to apply a cross-validation for a paragraph vector model:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from gensim.sklearn_api import D2VTransformer

data = pd.read_csv('https://pastebin.com/raw/bSGWiBfs')
np.random.seed(0)

X_train = data.apply(lambda r: simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), axis=1)
y_train = data.label

model = D2VTransformer(size=10, min_count=1, iter=5, seed=1)
clf = LogisticRegression(random_state=0)

pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('vec', model),
        ('clf', clf)
    ])

pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

score = pipeline.score(X_train, y_train)
print("Score:", score) # This works
cval = cross_val_score(pipeline, X_train, y_train, scoring='accuracy', cv=3)
print("Cross-Validation:", cval) # This doesn't work
```

> KeyError: 0

I experimented by replacing `X_train` in `cross_val_score` with `model.transform(X_train)` or `model.fit_transform(X_train)`. Also, I tried the same with raw input data (`data.text`), instead of pre-processed text. I suspect that something must be wrong with the format of `X_train` for the cross-validation, as compared to the `.score` function for Pipeline, which works just fine. I also noted that the `cross_val_score` worked with `CountVectorizer()`.

Does anyone spot the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this has nothing to do with transformation from `model`. Its related to `cross_val_score`.

`cross_val_score` will split the supplied data according the the `cv` param. For this, it will do something like this:

```
for train, test in splitter.split(X_train, y_train):
    new_X_train, new_y_train = X_train[train], y_train[train]
```

But your `X_train` is a `pandas.Series` object in which the index based selection does not work like this. See this:https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selection-by-position

Change this line:

```
X_train = data.apply(lambda r: simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), axis=1)
```

to:

```
# Access the internal numpy array
X_train = data.apply(lambda r: simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), axis=1).values

OR

# Convert series to list
X_train = data.apply(lambda r: simple_preprocess(r['text'], min_len=2), axis=1).tolist()
```